# Ignore Unix file permissions

Tags: unix, permissions

So I am working on a backup system, which will create a snapshot of a LVM volume, mount it and copy the files over to another server using `rdiff-backup`. Now this works well, however on the restoring part it keeps crashing. I've found out to be the issue that `aquota.group` is write protected, even for the root user.

I want to ignore this in some way, as I don't want to mess up with the permissions since those files should be intact because it's for backup and restore purposes. Gzipping the whole directory isn't an option either since `rdiff-backup` wouldn't work anymore then.

Anyone has an idea how I can still touch those files? The error I get is:

```
mv /mnt/hdd/rdiff-backup.tmp.4 /mnt/hdd/aquota.group
mv: overwrite `/mnt/hdd/aquota.group', overriding mode 0600? y
mv: cannot move `/mnt/hdd/rdiff-backup.tmp.4' to `/mnt/hdd/aquota.group': Operation not permitted
```

Comment: Are there ACLs define for the file or parent folder?

Comment: @Daniel Beck: I'm not sure, don't think so. Never worked with them before.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be much point in having a permission system if it could be easily circumvented from within the OS or filesystem. The only way to do this for a soundly designed filesystem would be to go outside the filesystem by writing your own filesystem drivers that ignore the file permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These aren't Unix permissions, since the error message is different. Most likely, the file has the "immutable" flag set on it; use `lsattr` to verify and `chattr` to change.

Comment: Yes, but then (as I also have different OS's to backup, not only Linux, also FreeBSD and Windows) there might be other complications. Is there any way to not change that `i` flag and still be able to change it? Else I would have to loop over the whole OS and change all files, and restore them later on. It would be a tedious task and I have tempered the OS's files.